# display "loading" on stackblitz

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/angular-internationalization-i18n-with-ngx-translate-tutorial/) in Angular , the code works on Visual Studio but on Stackblitz.com, I have a message -> `loading...`

I don't understand why nothing isn't display? I just did a copy/paste. It works correctly on Visual Studio, I don't understand why it does not work on Stackblitz.com?

The dependencies are:

```
npm install bootstrap
npm i @ngx-translate/core --save
npm i @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

Here is the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4kkluf?file=src/app/app.component.html

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix for you, You need to change the HTML selector in index.html. The selector you are using doesn't exist in your app, make the below change and it should work. `app-root` is your root component and `my-app` doesn't exist.

Index.html

```
<app-root>loading</app-root>
```